# Add an specific field from a PDF into the file name in a batch file

Tags: date, batch-file, rename

I'd like to add a specific field from a PDF into its file name in a batch file.

For example, there is a date on page 1 in the PDF file and I'd like to include that date in the name. How do I create the batch file?

In the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You can't.  Batch files can only read text files.

Comment: Whether it's possible depends on how the PDF is made. What's the output of `findstr /c:"Periods Ending" specific.pdf` (if any)?